# output csv with lines that contains only one column

Tags: bash, awk

with input csv file

```
sid,storeNo,latitude,longitude
2,1,-28.03720000,153.42921670
9
```

I wish to output only the lines with one column, in this example it's line 3.
how can this be done in bash shell script?

Answer (score 4):

**Using awk**

The following awk would be usfull

```
$ awk -F, 'NF==1' inputFile
9
```

**What it does?**

- `-F,` sets the field separator as `,`
- `NF==1` matches lines with `NF`, number of fields as 1. No action is provided hence default action, printing the entire record is taken. it is similar to `NF==1{print $0}`
- `inputFile` input csv file to the awk script

**Using grep**

The same function can also be done using `grep`

```
$ grep -v ',' inputFile
9
```

- `-v` option prints lines that do not match the pattern
- `,` along with `-v` greps matches lines that do not contain `,` field separator

**Using sed**

```
$ sed -n '/^[^,]*$/p' inputFile
9
```

**what it does?**

- `-n` suppresses normal printing of pattern space
- `'/^[^,]*$/` selects lines that match the pattern, lines without any `,`

  - `^` anchors the regex at the start of the string
  - `[^,]*` matches anything other than `,`
  - `$` anchors string at the end of string
- `p` action `p` makes sed to print the current pattern space, that is pattern space matching the input

Comment: The `awk` is most flexible.  If you like the first two fields, just do: `awk -F, 'NF<3'`

Comment: `NF==1{print $0}` `=>` `NF==1`

Comment: @gboffi Is it a question or statement?

Comment: Neither one, it is a simplification proposal... maybe an excessive simplification, for sure a cryptic one.  I'm sorry I've been so terse, ciao from

Comment: @gboffi but thats what i wrote in answer at the first place, `NF==1`.

Comment: I'm embarassed... I went confused when I read the answer, causing the following misunderstandings, my sincerest apologies.

Comment: @gboffi its alright :) . i was wondering if you didnt get what why i wrote `NF==1`

Answer (score 0):

try this `bash` script

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line
do
        IFS=","
        set -- $line
        case ${#} in
         1) echo $line;;
         *) continue;;
        esac
done < file
```