# output the rows with one non-empty column in csv using bash

Tags: bash, csv, awk

Given a csv file, I want to output only the rows with exactly one non-empty column.

input file

```
"a","b","c"
"d","",""
```

output:

```
"d","",""
```

Can this be done in bash?

Comment: wow, homework? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795558/output-csv-with-lines-that-contains-only-one-column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler awk solution can  be

```
$ awk '/^("",)*"."(,"")*$/' inputFile
"d","",""
```

**What it does**

- `/^("",)*"."(,"")*$/` patterns matches as

  - `("",)` number of empty columns
  - `"."` followed by *ONE* non empty column
  - `(,"")` further followed by number of empty columns
- no action specified, hence takes the default action to print the entire record

**EDIT**

If there are more than one letter in a column

```
$ awk '/^("",)*"[^"]+"(,"")*$/' input
"d","",""
```

Thanks to  Jotne

Comment: What id there are more than one letter in the column?  Eks `"do it","",""`

Comment: @Jotne good point !! edited the answer to include that as well . Thank you

Comment: I don't see the point of catching groups of `"",`. Just making sure there is a combination of `"` and `,` is enough. See my answer.

Comment: @fedorqui am such a fool !!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` for this:

```
sed -n '/^[",]*[^",]*[",]*$/p' file
```

To make sure it does not match blank lines we can add the `+`:

```
sed -n '/^[",]*"[^",]\+"[",]*$/p' file
```

It returns:

```
"d","",""
```

It is a matter of checking if there is one, and just one, block characters different than `"` or `,` in between these characters. `-n` inhibits the printing, whereas `p` prints the lines that accomplish the condition.

Comment: What if one of the field contain an embedded `,`? This script will print this line `",","","abcd"`, when it should not...

Comment: Yes... it could happen. I won't update, though, because I would then have the same answer as other people. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: I would request you to add a NOTE in the answer for this corner case, just for completeness sake...

Answer (score 2):

You could use `gsub()` to count the number of times an empty field is found, then subtract from `NF` and test equal to one. Here's one way using GNU AWK and the [FPAT variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html):

```
awk 'BEGIN { FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" } NF - gsub(/""/, "&") == 1' file
```

If you don't have embedded commas, you could simply write:

```
awk -F, 'NF - gsub(/""/, "&") == 1' file
```

Comment: +1 Nice Answer ! Could be shortened to `awk -F, 'NF-gsub(/""/,"&")==1'` though :)

Comment: As anishsane pointed out in a comment, this also will fail with fields containing `,` like `"","1,2",""` not being printed. Some other poster works ok with this.

Comment: FPAT is nice to use with comma separated CSV files :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Through sed.

```
$ sed -rn '/^(".[^"]*"(,"")*|""(,"")*,".[^"]*"(,"")*)$/p' file
"d","",""
```

First part `".[^"]*"(,"")*` matches these type of string `"A","",""` where the second part `""(,"")*,".[^"]*"(,"")*` would match these type of string formats `"","","A"`

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
"a","b","c"
"d","",""
"","","A"
"A","","A"
"","A",""
"","A","A"
"A","A",""
$ sed -rn '/^(".[^"]*"(,"")*|""(,"")*,".[^"]*"(,"")*)$/p' file
"d","",""
"","","A"
"","A",""
```

Comment: What id there are more than one letter in the column?  Eks `"do it","",""`

Answer (score 1):

A simplistic approach which assumes that no fields in the CSV file contain commas:

```
awk -F '[",]+' '{n=0;for(i=2;i<NF;++i)$i~/^$/||++n}n==1' file.txt
```

Set the input field separator to one or more double quotes and commas. Loop through all of the fields, incrementing `n` for every non-empty field. If the total number is exactly 1, print the line.

The reason that the loop goes from field `2` to `NF-1` is that the first and last field are before and after the parts that you are interested in.

Very similar but ever-so-slightly shorter:

```
awk -F ',' '{n=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)$i~/""/||++n}n==1' file.txt
```

Use the comma as the field separator and increment `n` for any fields that contain `""`. In this case, the loop goes through each field.

Answer (score 0):

This `grep` should be able to handle this:

```
grep -E '^("",)*"[^"]+"(,"")*$' file
"d","",""
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split the line into fields and count how many are non-empty:

```
$ awk -F'^"|","|"$' '{c=0; for (i=2; i<NF; i++) if ($i != "") ++c} c==1' file
"d","",""
```

The loop starts at 2 and ends at NF-1 because there's no point checking the empty fields that will always exist before the first and after the last "real" fields (i.e. before the `^"` and after the `"$`) when the line is split using an FS that includes the start-of-string (`^`) and end-of-string (`$`) RE metacharacters.

If you ever wanted to check different counts of non-empty fields, just change the number you compare `c` to:

```
$ cat file
"a","b","c"
"d","",""
"e","","f"
"","",""
```

.

```
$ awk -F'^"|","|"$' '{c=0; for (i=2; i<NF; i++) if ($i != "") ++c} c==0' file
"","",""
$ awk -F'^"|","|"$' '{c=0; for (i=2; i<NF; i++) if ($i != "") ++c} c==1' file
"d","",""
$ awk -F'^"|","|"$' '{c=0; for (i=2; i<NF; i++) if ($i != "") ++c} c==2' file
"e","","f"
$ awk -F'^"|","|"$' '{c=0; for (i=2; i<NF; i++) if ($i != "") ++c} c==3' file
"a","b","c"
$ awk -F'^"|","|"$' '{c=0; for (i=2; i<NF; i++) if ($i != "") ++c} c==4' file
$
```